# Plotting country as a polygon

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, geography

I am trying to reproduce an example from Geographics.

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Italy]]
```

It does not work.
Using Ctrl+= this way:

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Ctrl+= Italy]]
```

Does not work either.
What keys do I need to use before Italy to make this work?

Comment: The second option should work.  You could also try `GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]]]`.  Also, you're running Mathematica 10 or above, right?  GeoGraphics didn't exist in MM 9 or earlier.

Comment: I am actually experiencing a weird behavior here: CTRL+= generates a WolframAlpha inline input field, but when I press enter to retrieve the result it fails, complaining that it doesn't have internet access. On the other hand, I can use `= Italy` at the beginning of an empty line, which should be equivalent, and it works fine. I can also use `== Italy` and that works as well. Clearly there is nothing wrong with Internet access from within *Mathematica*, but still the inline form doesn't work for me either. Was that what you experienced as well?

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by Michael Seifert in a comment `GeoGraphics[Polygon[`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>`Italy]]` should work (it worked for me), but if you want do it without using Wolfram's server, try

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: italy]